# Почему возвращает false. PHP

Tags: php

```
    function securecode(){
    $Curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($Curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://karton.ua/securecode/check?sid='.$_GET['sid'],
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_REFERER => $_SERVER['REFERER'],
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
    ));

    $res = curl_exec($Curl);
    curl_close($Curl);

    $location = stristr($res, 'location:');
    $url = stristr($location, 'https://');
    $resExp = explode('/', $url);
    $resEnd = end($resExp);
    $resl = (string)$resEnd=="fail"?true:false;

    var_dump($resl);
    if($resl == "fail"){
        headerLocation('https://site/safedeal/payment/result.php?res=fail');
        masseges($_GET['sum'], $_GET['url']);
    }else{
        headerLocation('https://site/safedeal/payment/result.php?res=ok');
    }
}
```

Есть вот такая функция! Результатом curl является заголовок с редиректом на статус оплаты:
**Положительная** https://karton.ua/status/ok

**Отрицательная** https://karton.ua/status/fail

Так вот я проверяю конец ссылки и узнаю прошла ли оплата или нет. Но я не могу понять почему `$resl = (string)$resEnd=="fail"?true:false;` Возвращает fasle;

Comment: А сделать `var_dump($resEnd)` вы не можете? Два вардампа в скрипте это перебор, понимаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$resl = (string)$resEnd=="fail"?true:false;
```

Эта переменная будет `true` если последнее слово "fail", и `false` в остальных случаях.

Далее вы в `boolean` переменной ищите строку "false", которой явно нет, поэтому условие никогда не будет истинным.

Я бы написал этот кусок кода вот так:

```
$resl = $resEnd=="ok"?true:false;
if($resl){
   headerLocation('https://site/safedeal/payment/result.php?res=ok');
}else{
   headerLocation('https://site/safedeal/payment/result.php?res=fail');
   masseges($_GET['sum'], $_GET['url']);
}
```

Comment: я бы сразу в if добавил $resEnd=="ok". Не вижу смысла короткого ифа который bool возвращает

Comment: @JurijJazdanov, я его специально не убирал, чтобы можно было понять разницу в коде, и как это работает.